# Vagrant bash script not responding

Tags: bash, vagrant

I'm learning vagrant and trying to edit the vagrantfile of my project to install some necessary packages, updates etc.

The code below is my *bootstrap.sh* bash script. It's a bit rough but it should have worked but doesn't.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Updating ...."
apt-get update -y > /dev/null

echo "Upgrading ..."
apt-get upgrade -y > /dev/null

echo "Installing packages ..."
apt-get install taskel tree -y > /dev/null

echo "Installing drush ..."
wget https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases/download/8.1.17/drush.phar > /dev/null
mv drush.phar drush > /dev/null
mv drush /usr/local/bin/drush > /dev/null
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/drush > /dev/null
drush version > /dev/null

if ! [ -L /var/www ]; then
  # rm -rf /var/www
  # ln -fs /vagrant /var/www
fi
```

And my Vagrantfile contains the following:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://vagrantcloud.com/search.
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"

  # Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
  # boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs
  # `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
  # config.vm.box_check_update = false

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  # NOTE: This will enable public access to the opened port
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine and only allow access
  # via 127.0.0.1 to disable public access
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  # config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  # config.vm.network "public_network"

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  # config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:
  #
  # config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  #   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
  #   vb.gui = true
  #
  #   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
  #   vb.memory = "1024"
  # end
  #
  # View the documentation for the provider you are using for more
  # information on available options.

  # Enable provisioning with a shell script. Additional provisioners such as
  # Puppet, Chef, Ansible, Salt, and Docker are also available. Please see the
  # documentation for more information about their specific syntax and use.
  # config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  #   apt-get update
  #   apt-get install -y apache2
  # SHELL

  Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
    config.vm.provision :shell, path: "preplogs/bootstrap.sh"
  end

end
```

I run **vagrant up** but there's not indication bootstrap.sh executes and when I ssh into the box, none of my packages are installed.

Comment: Does `vagrant reload` help? Your provision is not being read, it is read only on 1st `vagrant up`

Comment: @brokenfoot No!. I executed vagrant reload, vagrant up and then vagrant ssh but my script still did not come into effect.

Comment: `vagrant reload && vagrant ssh` should be enough. You could `strace vagrant reload && vagrant ssh` and see if it is even trying to read provision script, what path etc..

Comment: I've just tried this, and it worked fine! I put the `Vagrantfile` and `bootstrap.sh` in the same directory then `vagrant up`, and the updates ran as expected. What happens if you `vagrant destroy -f` the instance and try `up` again?

Comment: Still don't understand this. Nothing I've tried of the suggestions above is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

I had duplicated the `Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|` and `end` sections.
If you look at my full Vagrantfile contents in my question you would see what I was doing wrong.

It wasn't clear to me until I opened the file in an editor instead of the terminal.

Thanks to @brokenfoot and @Jon for their assistance and input.